# Adding search bar programmatically to tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have an textfield which represents an tableview as its inputview. I want to add 2 things to this tableview.

1) add a search bar.
2) add cancell button to top of tableview.

```
class enterYourDealVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

var dealAirports = [
    airPorts(name: "Airport1", shortcut: "AP1")!),
    airPorts(name: "Airport2", shortcut: "AP2")!)
]
var filteredAirports = [airPorts]()


//view did load
    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    toTextField.inputView = self.tableView

//here is my search function
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredAirports = dealAirports.filter { ap in
        return ap.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

The problem is with this code, it doesn't search. Also when I click the search bar it dismiss the tableview and returns me back to viewcontroller. How can I fix this?

and how can I add cancel button to this tableview?

Comment: UISearchController Apple sample code : [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) 
This will help you to implement.

Comment: It could help me if I knew objective c.. It looks very complicated to me. I'll keep examining the code.

Comment: The sample code is not opening running properly under Xcode 10.

Comment: @jsloop yeah the question is asked 3 years ago. It might be the reason.

Answer (score 20):

This will add a SeachBar

```
lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
     searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.default
    searchBar.placeholder = " Search..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String)
{
    ...your code...
}
```

Comment: `navigationItem.titleView` is pretty brilliant. Keeps it sticky which is great for some uses. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

**Step1**

Add UISearchBarDelegate to your view controller.

**Step2**

```
//Write this code in viewDidLoad() or your required function
let searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
//IF you want frame replace first line and comment "searchBar.sizeToFit()"
//let searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: headerView.frame.width-20, height: headerView.frame.height-20))
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
searchBar.placeholder = " Search..."
searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchBar.isTranslucent = false
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
searchBar.delegate = self
yourViewName.addSubview(searchBar)//Here change your view name
```

**Step3**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String) {
    //your code here....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code snipet in swift for the same For more just refer Apple Doc mentioned in comment.

**UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in IOS8.0, and recommended to use UISearchController**

Hope this will help you alot

**ContactTVC**

```
class ContactTVC:UITableViewController{   
// MARK: Types
/// State restoration values.
enum RestorationKeys : String {
    case viewControllerTitle
    case searchControllerIsActive
    case searchBarText
    case searchBarIsFirstResponder
}

struct SearchControllerRestorableState {
    var wasActive = false
    var wasFirstResponder = false
}


/*
 The following 2 properties are set in viewDidLoad(),
 They an implicitly unwrapped optional because they are used in many other places throughout this view controller
 */

/// Search controller to help us with filtering.
var searchController: UISearchController!

/// Secondary search results table view.
var resultsTableController: ResultsTableController!

/// Restoration state for UISearchController
var restoredState = SearchControllerRestorableState()
var arrayContacts: Array<CNContact> = []
var searchResultArrayContacts: Array<CNContact> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultsTableController = ResultsTableController()
// We want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath(_:) is called for both tables.
    resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // default is YES
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self    // so we can monitor text changes + others

  /*
     Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
     presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
     hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
     */

    definesPresentationContext = true

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Restore the searchController's active state.
    if restoredState.wasActive {
        searchController.active = restoredState.wasActive
        restoredState.wasActive = false

        if restoredState.wasFirstResponder {
            searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
            restoredState.wasFirstResponder = false
        }
    }
}

//MARK override TableViewDelegates/Datasource methods  
}
extension ContactTVC: UISearchResultsUpdating{

// MARK: UISearchResultsUpdating

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        if let text = searchController.searchBar.text where (text.isEmpty == false){
        {

                            // Hand over the filtered results to our search results table.

                            let resultsController = searchController.searchResultsController as! ResultsTableController

                            resultsController.filteredProducts = Array(searchResult)

                            resultsController.tableView.reloadData()

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.tableViewContacts.reloadData()
                        })

                }   
         }
}
}
//MARK: SearchBarDelegate
extension ContactTVC: UISearchBarDelegate{

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if let text = searchBar.text where (text.isEmpty == false) {

          // update the search result array by filtering….


                if searchResult.count > 0{

                    self.searchResultArrayContacts = Array(searchResult)
                }
                else{

                    self.searchResultArrayContacts = Array(self.arrayContacts)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableViewContacts.reloadData()
                })
     }
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.text = nil
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

}
}
```

**/// The table view controller responsible for displaying the filtered products as the user types in the search field.**

```
class ResultsTableController: UITableViewController {
// MARK: Properties

let reusableIdentifier = "contactCell"

var filteredProducts = [CNContact]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self
    self.tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self

}


// MARK: UITableViewDataSource
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return filteredProducts.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =  UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reusableIdentifier)

     var contact = CNContact()
     contact = filteredProducts[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = contact.givenName

    let phones = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value as! CNPhoneNumber

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = phones.stringValue

    return cell
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

//first write delegate for search "UISearchBarDelegate"
//MARK:- Search button action

```
@IBAction func searchWithAddress(_ sender: Any) {
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4+**

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var maintableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchUIBar: UISearchBar!
        
    var isSearch : Bool = false
    var tableData = ["Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Bahrain","Brazil", "Cuba", "Denmark","Denmark", "Georgia", "Hong Kong", "Iceland", "India", "Japan", "Kuwait", "Nepal"];
    var filteredTableData:[String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        maintableView.dataSource = self
        maintableView.delegate = self
        searchUIBar.delegate = self
        maintableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    //MARK: UISearchbar delegate
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
           isSearch = true
    }
       
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
           searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
           isSearch = false
    }
       
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
           searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
           isSearch = false
    }
       
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
           searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
           isSearch = false
    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.count == 0 {
            isSearch = false
            self.maintableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            filteredTableData = tableData.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
                let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
                let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
                return range.location != NSNotFound
            })
            if(filteredTableData.count == 0){
                isSearch = false
            } else {
                isSearch = true
            }
            self.maintableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

```
extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = maintableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if (isSearch) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
            print(tableData[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
    }

    }

    extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         if(isSearch) {
             return filteredTableData.count
         }else{
            return tableData.count
        }
         
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.