# TableView SearchBar doesn't work: Index out of range

Tags: swift, uikit, uisearchbar

I know there are some similar questions, but it's doesn't work to me. I'm new to this, so I followed some tutorial trying make a search bar in my table view screen.
I got a problem: there are index out of range and I cannot realise why.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

final class AllGroupsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var groups = [
        "cats",
        "birds",
        "dogs",
        "books",
        "music",
        "movies",
        "art",
        "science",
        "tech",
        "beauty",
    ]
    
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    var isSearching = false
    var filteredData = [String]()
    
    var userGroups: [String] = []
    var groupSectionTitles = [String]()
    var groupsDictionary = [String: [String]]()

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(
            nibName: "GroupCell",
            bundle: nil),
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
        
        for group in groups {
            let groupKey = String(group.prefix(1))
            if var groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
                groupValues.append(group)
                groupsDictionary[groupKey] = groupValues
            } else {
                groupsDictionary[groupKey] = [group]
            }
        }
        
        
        groupSectionTitles = [String](groupsDictionary.keys)
        groupSectionTitles = groupSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return groupSectionTitles.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if isSearching {
            return filteredData.count
        } else {
            return groups.count
        }
        
        let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[section]
        if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
            return groupValues.count
        }
        
        return 0
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return groupSectionTitles[section]
    }
    
    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return groupSectionTitles
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as? GroupCell
        else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        var currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]
        
        let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
        if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
            currentGroup = groupValues[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        if isSearching {
            currentGroup = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
        
        cell.configure(
            photo: UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill") ?? UIImage(),
            name: currentGroup)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        defer {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
        
        let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
        var currentGroup = ""
        if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
            currentGroup = groupValues[indexPath.row] // here is index out of range
        }
        
        if userGroups.firstIndex(of: currentGroup) == nil {
            userGroups.append(currentGroup)
        }
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addGroup", sender: nil)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "addGroup",
               let myGroupsViewController = segue.destination as? MyGroupsViewController {
                myGroupsViewController.groups = userGroups
        }
    }
}

extension AllGroupsViewController {
     
     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
         filteredData = groups.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
         isSearching = true
         tableView.reloadData()
     }
     
     func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         isSearching = false
         searchBar.text = ""
         tableView.reloadData()
     }
 }
```

I'll be so glad if somebody will help me. And, please, can you recommend me some good tutorial to achieve my aim?

Comment: It looks like you've successfully integrated the `isSearching` flag in `cellForRowAt` method, but you are not checking that in `didSelectRowAt:`. Using `filteredData` should resolve the matter.

Comment: @EDUsta unfortunately it's still doesn't work :(

Comment: Where does the crash happen ? When you are typing in search bar or some other time like when scrolling ? Maybe it will help to get an idea if possible with screenshot, what you are trying to achieve. Finally what data is in `filteredData` ? Maybe you can add some of this information to your question to make it more clear

Comment: @ShawnFrank crash happened when I'm trying to add some new table view cell from another controller, you can watch it [here](https://youtu.be/fjfQ5n0LH7E). But its works correctly when there are no SearchBar. `filteredData` is for search results.

Comment: Hmm, I saw the video - did not fully get it, you tap `+` and the app crashes ? Is `+` button bringing user to screen with code above ? So crash looks like it happens as soon as you come on this screen ? Does xcode tell you which line of code has index out of range ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank When there are no code above for search bar, when I tap `+` another screen with table view cells has appears. In the code above I marked the line of code has index out of range when some code for SearchBar is here.

Comment: I think you should do `isSearching` check in `didSelectRowAt` like you did in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` because the data source changes based on `isSearching` so do this check also in `didSelectRowAt` and maybe it will help ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank it's still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: can you update the code to repo like before and share it here, I will have a look a bit later to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @ShawnFrank [here](https://github.com/tpolinas/UI_l1) it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually issue is more to do with logic of accessing groups than crash because of adding search bar.

For example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if isSearching {
        return filteredData.count
    } else {
        return groups.count
    }
    
    let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[section]
    if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
        return groupValues.count
    }
    
    return 0
}
```

Here because you use `if-else` you will either return `filteredData.count` when searching or `groups.count` - you will not go beyond this code

So when you are not searching, you will return `groups.count` which is `10` and that is wrong because you want to return the count for which section we are in, for example `a` should return `1`, `b` should return `3`.

The logic **after** `if-else` block should replace logic in `else` section

Now looking at next two functions:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    guard let cell
            = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell",
                                            for: indexPath) as? GroupCell
    else { return UITableViewCell() }
    
    var currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]
    
    let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
        currentGroup = groupValues[indexPath.row]
    }
    
    if isSearching {
        currentGroup = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
    
    cell.configure(
        photo: UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill") ?? UIImage(),
        name: currentGroup)
    
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    defer {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    var currentGroup = ""
    if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
        currentGroup = groupValues[indexPath.row] // here is index out of range
    }
    
    if userGroups.firstIndex(of: currentGroup) == nil {
        userGroups.append(currentGroup)
    }
    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addGroup", sender: nil)
}
```

First because `numberOfRowsInSection` returns wrong values, we will have issues in these functions.

Then I think the logic of accessing the right data source of groups, group sections is not done right.

For example: `currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAt indexPath` is not right because this gets group from group array of 10 when we only want to group for the specific section.

And also I see `return cell` twice so code after the first will not be run.

So what I did is just refactored these functions to make it more clear and added some comments.

First, we need to keep in mind the different data sources:

```
// All the groups
var groups = [
    "cats",
    "birds",
    "dogs",
    "books",
    "music",
    "movies",
    "art",
    "science",
    "tech",
    "beauty",
]

// Checks if search is active or not
var isSearching = false

// This will hold the filtered array when searching
var filteredData = [String]()

// This will hold groups of the user
var userGroups: [String] = []

// This will hold section prefixes [a, b, c, etc]
var groupSectionTitles = [String]()

// This will hold mapping of prefixes to groups
// [a: [art], b: [beauty, books], etc]
var groupsDictionary = [String: [String]]()
```

There is nothing different above from your code, only comments, however we have to keep a visual image of this because this is important to how we need to access the data

Next, I created this function to get the correct groups in a section since we need to do this many times

```
private func getGroups(in section: Int) -> [String]
{
    // The current section should be got from groupSectionTitles
    let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[section]
    
    var groupsInSection: [String] = []
    
    // Get groups for current section
    if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
        groupsInSection = groupValues
    }
    
    // Change groups in section if searching
    if isSearching {
        groupsInSection = filteredData
    }
    
    return groupsInSection
}
```

Then I refactored these functions slightly:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if isSearching {
        return filteredData.count
    } else {
        let groupsInSection = getGroups(in: section)
        return groupsInSection.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    guard let cell
            = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell",
                                            for: indexPath) as? GroupCell
    else { return UITableViewCell() }
    
    let groupsInSection = getGroups(in: indexPath.section)
    
    cell.configure(
        photo: UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill") ?? UIImage(),
        name: groupsInSection[indexPath.row])
    
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let groupsInSection = getGroups(in: indexPath.section)
    let currentGroup = groupsInSection[indexPath.row]
    
    if userGroups.firstIndex(of: currentGroup) == nil {
        userGroups.append(currentGroup)
    }
    
    defer {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addGroup", sender: nil)
}
```

I think now your crash will be resolved and things work as expected.

However, since you did not connect and implement search delegate yet, maybe there can be some issues when `isSearching` becomes true but I think that can be for another question on filtering with search delegate.

For tutorials, you can have a look at:

[UISearchResultsController tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5ob4TXIK90&ab_channel=KwipApps) - watch from minute 8 onwards

[UISearchBar tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH67DkBx9Jc&t=19s&ab_channel=AjayGandecha) - watch from minute 10 onwards

[StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508720/adding-search-bar-programmatically-to-tableview-in-swift)

Comment: thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @t_polinas - happy to help. I just add small update in the end of my answer with links to tutorial for search bar as I forgot it so hope that helps.